# Convert array to a printed string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to convert array to a string with square brackets and all.

This is the array

```
$content =['a', 'b', 'c'] ;
```

The output I need is,

```
$contstring = "['a', 'b', 'c']" ;
```

A printed array.

```
Implode()
```

or  `serialize()` 
doesn't do the job. Please suggest me a way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP has this magical concatenation operator: `$contentstring = "['" . implode("', '",$content) . "']";`

Comment: Why `implode` doesn't do the job? It is exactly what you need

Comment: `Implode` prints the values. But I need the string with square brackets.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much for the answer

Comment: What you need is `json_encode`

Comment: I tried `json_encode` as well. But it didn't work. @Mark 's answer did the job. Thanks @SergeyLebedev and @u_mulder for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get exactly what you want you just need to use implode with `', '` as your glue:

```
$content =['a', 'b', 'c'] ;
$contstring = "['" . implode($content, "', '") . "']" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`implode()` joins elements in array. basically :

```
$a = ['m','e','m','o'];
$str = implode($a,'');
echo $str;
// or : echo implode($a,'');
```

or make your own loop :

```
$str = '';
foreach($a as $c){
    $str .= $c;
}
echo $str;
```